# Finding the Nth Fibonacci number through input field PHP

Tags: php, input, field, fibonacci

I'm having some issues getting the input code to work with the equation. I've been trying for a while (I'm new to coding) and searching, while not being able to make it work in any way. This is what I ended up with. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<br />Choose a number to be the nth in the Fibonacci sequence: <input type="number" name="fibnum">
<input type="submit">
</form> <br /> <br />

<?php


if(isset($_POST['fibnum'])){


    $fibnum = $_POST['fibnum'];


    function fibRec($fibnum){

        if ($fibnum < 0){
        echo "There are no Fibonacci numbers of negative values.";
        }
            elseif ($fibnum == 0){

                echo "0";
            }

                elseif ($fibnum == 1){

                    echo "1";
                }

                    else {

                        $sum = fibRec($fibnum-1)+fibRec($fibnum-2); 
                        echo $sum;
                    }

    }
        $fib = fibRec($fibnum); 
        echo $fib;          

}           
?>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u post the error u r getting does the post array have the fibnum variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it work all you need to do is change the echo's to returns like so:

```
<?php
$_POST['fibnum']=11;

if(isset($_POST['fibnum'])){


    $fibnum = $_POST['fibnum'];


    function fibRec($fibnum){

        if ($fibnum < 0){
        return ( "There are no Fibonacci numbers of negative values.");
        }
            elseif ($fibnum == 0){

                return ("0");
            }

                elseif ($fibnum == 1){

                    return ("1");
                }

                    else {

                        $sum = fibRec($fibnum-1)+fibRec($fibnum-2); 
                        return ($sum);
                    }

    }
        $fib = fibRec($fibnum); 
        echo $fib;          

}           
?>
```

working demo: http://ideone.com/e0xeY7

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, when I input higher numbers it take a lot of time to load, can I make it quicker?

Comment: If I needed this I wouldn't caculate on the fly but put the first million in a db table

Comment: I'm gonna need to make this code into a db table using SQL?

Comment: Need? It's totally your call ☺ wouldn't suprise me if one wasn't available online

Answer (score 0):

you were pushing integers into echo.  in a recursive formula, returning the value goes back to the calling entity, not automatically outside the function.

Take a look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<br />Choose a number to be the nth in the Fibonacci sequence: <input type="number" name="fibnum">
<input type="submit">
</form> <br /> <br />

<?php


if(isset($_POST['fibnum'])){


    $fibnum = $_POST['fibnum'];


    function fibRec($fibnum){

        if ($fibnum < 0){
        echo "There are no Fibonacci numbers of negative values.";
        }
            elseif ($fibnum == 0){

                return 0;
            }

                elseif ($fibnum == 1){

                    return 1;
                }

                    else {

                        $sum = fibRec($fibnum-1)+fibRec($fibnum-2); 
                        return $sum;
                    }

    }
        $fib = fibRec($fibnum); 
        echo $fib;          

}           
?>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `PHI` constant associated with golden ratio to calculate nth fibonacci number. it is considered that fibonnaci number until 5th iteration are not as per golden ratio so you can have it like below :

```
<?php 

$fibnum = intval($_POST['fibnum']);

const PHI = 1.6180339887;
$f = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3];

echo getNthFibo($fibnum);

function getNthFibo($i)
{
    if($i < 5){
        return $f[$i];
    }

    // Starting from 5th iteration of fibo function
    $n = 5;
    $fn = 3;

    while ($n < $i) { 
        $fn = round($fn * PHI); 
        $n++; 
    }

    return $fn; 
}
```